# What's the idea of "layer" in Webpack 5?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

As title. I'm learning Webpack 5, and I just noticed there seems to be a concept called "layer" that is rarely mentioned(or I haven't found) in the documentation. It can be found [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#entry-descriptor) (for the intro. of top-level `entry` field):

```js
    personal: {
      // ...
      layer: 'name of layer', // set the layer for an entry point
    },
  },
};
```

and [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunkslayer) (for the built-in plugin `SplitChunksPlugin`):

```js
splitChunks.cacheGroups.{cacheGroup}.layer
```

> Assign modules to a cache group by module layer.

Are these two `layer`s have the same meaning? If not, what are the definitions? Could you also point out the advantage(s) of using them? (I don't even know how to use it... at all)

Comment: It's also mentioned by https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rulelayer : "Specify the layer in which the module should be placed in. A group of modules could be united in one layer which could then be used in split chunks, stats or entry options."

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's a way of grouping modules - I suppose as a kind of hint to Webpack how to split up modules?

Comment: @RichardHunter Now I have the same conclusion. I didn't have a deep dive into webpack when I asked the question.