# what is the layer and issuerLayer mean in webpack5? can show some examples?

Tags: webpack-5

I don't understand the webpack [rule.layer options](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rulelayer) , in which scenarios these two options can be used? Can someone help me out?

I just configured this option in the rule, but nothing happend when I run build.  what should i do?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71747432/whats-the-idea-of-layer-in-webpack-5